# How to avoid http sniffer from get private api from your code

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, packet-sniffers

I found a python compiled exe file that avoid http sniffer.It written in python 2.7.

when I run a sniffer it will freeze the code.I want to write the same property into my own code in latest python version.I cant find a solution for my problem.

Comment: usually python .exe is NOT real compiled but it is only self-extracting .zip file and you can get source code.

Comment: its obfuscated.

Comment: I don't know method to freeze code so the only method is to get source code (even if it obfuscated) and dig in this code

Comment: it probably sleep module that running on different thread and it got triggered when some conditions met.